# How to extract parameters from fitted model for ListSurfacePlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, fitting

I would like to obtain the parameters used by Mathematica to create this surface fit of 3d data:

```
data = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {4, 2, 8}, {1, 2, 5}, {3, 3,
 1}};
e = ListPointPlot3D[data];
f = ListSurfacePlot3D[data];
Show[e, f]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the plotparameters try

```
??e
??f
```

Comment: Lovely, thank you! And sorry, is there a way to obtain an equation for the fitted surface?

Comment: Try `Interpolation[f[[1, 1]] ][x,y]`